# What is "the quotient of the universal ordinary Hecke algebra corresponding to an ordinary $\Lambda$-adic form"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hida-theory

Let $\Lambda := \Bbb Z_p[[T]]$ be the usual Iwasawa algebra. In [Jha and Sujatha - On the Hida deformations of fine Selmer groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2011.02.042) on page 181, the authors refer to the quotient $\Bbb H^{\text{ord}}_{\mathcal{F}}$ of the universal ordinary Hecke algebra $\Bbb H^{\text{ord}}_{Np^\infty}$ corresponding to an ordinary $\Lambda$-adic eigenform $\mathcal{F}$. I'm somewhat new to the subject and have been asked to give this paper a go by my masters supervisor, and while I "know" what all of these objects are, Hida's original 1986 paper doesn't explicitly say "the quotient of blah corresponding to blah" and I don't know how to make this connection. Could someone explain this to me like I'm five?

Comment: Surely this must be the quotient by the ideal of operators which send that eigenform to zero.

Comment: Hi @WillSawin, why surely? Does this have nothing to do with the local rings which occur in the decomposition of $\Bbb H_{Np^\infty}^\text{ord} \otimes_{\Lambda} \text{Quot}(\Lambda)$?

Comment: Just because the authors treat it as obvious and it's the only quotient of a Hecke algebra associated to a form that seems obvious to me. The quotient produced here is finite flat over $\Lambda$, and when you tensor with $\operatorname{Quot}(\Lambda)$ should be a field, so this is the quotient by a maximal ideal of the tensor product you write down. If I understand what you say correctly, I guess it must be the maximal ideal of one of the local rings. (Or if you really mean local fields, the quotient after tensoring should be one of these local fields.)